# Error invalid operands to binary

Tags: c

I am a beginner and I am using dev c++ . I am trying to write a function to determine which quadrant it lies in. Its fairly simple, but I am getting an error [Error] invalid operands to binary << (have 'float' and 'int')

```
#include <stdio.h>
int quadrant (float i, float j);
int main()
{
    float a,b;
    int c;
    scanf ("%f,%f",&a,&b);
    c=quadrant(a,b);
    printf("the given point lies in %d quadrant",c);
    return 0;
}
int quadrant (float i, float  j)
{
    if (i>>0 && j>>0)
    return 1;
    else if (i>>0 && j<<0)
    return 4;
    else if (i<<0 && j>>0)
    return 2;
    else if (i<<0 && j<<0)
    return 3;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Is it because float numbers cant be used with binary operands?
I replaced floats with int, all the floats. This time when I compile I get error ID: return 1 status.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Float operands can't be used with _bitwise_ operators like bit shifting. ("Binary" operators are operators that have two operands.)

Comment: Have you confused the bit-shift operators `<<` and `>>` with the comparison operators less than `<` and greater than `>`? These can, of course, be used with floating-point numbers.

Comment: You don't want `>>` and `<<`, which are shift operators.  You just want `>` or `<` or `>=` or `<=`.

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got confused between Comparison Operators `< , > , <= , >= , !=` and Bitwise operator `<< >>` . Replace your Bitwise operators with corresponding Comparison operators.

```
int quadrant (float i, float  j)
{
    if (i>0 && j>0)
    return 1;
    else if (i>0 && j<0)
    return 4;
    else if (i<0 && j>0)
    return 2;
    else if (i<0 && j<0)
    return 3;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe it should be `>=` etc.